# Android change webview URL depending on user's coountry

Tags: android, webview, country

I'm making an application that shows a Webview and changes the URL's extension depending on country. Should I make two separate applications for both countries or is there a way to easily fix this in programming?

The URL is defined in my CommonCode as following:

```
public static String pBaseUrl = "http://url.be/";
```

That's how it's like for Belgium, for the Netherlands it should be "http://url.nl"

Answer (score 2):

If you put the url in the strings.xml you can just use the `Localization` of android

By using the country specific folders:

```
/res/values-nl/strings.xml
/res/values-be/strings.xml
```

More information : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I would recommend using the mcc qualifier instead of the language qualifier, because the language can be changed by the user.

Comment: seems like a good answer, but I eventually decided to use the user's current location as that turned out to be a more viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String locale = this.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

to get country code and replace current URL's extension with this one.